# Many to Many laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following situation:
The database table "Movies" has a many to many relation with "Actors"

[This is the relation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvOWw.png)

Now I need to get all the movies that have the actors with for example ID 1, 8, 20

How can I do this with the query builder from Laravel 5.4?

```
class Movie extends Model
{
    public function actors(){
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Actor', 'movies_has_actors', 'movie_id', 'actor_id');
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function actors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Actor', 'users_has_actors', 'user_id', 'actor_id')->withPivot('rating', 'favorite')->wherePivot('user_id', $this->id);
    }
    public function functionName(){
        $actor_ids = $this->actors()->where('users_has_actors.rating', '>=', 8)->pluck('id');
        $movie_model = new Movie();
        $movies = $movie_model->actors()->wherePivotIn('actor_id', $actor_ids);
    }
}
```

I am trying it like above, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Get actor where id is equal to $id, and eager load movies.
$actor = Actor::where('id', '=', $actor_id)->with('movies')->get();


// If you want to get actors with an array of IDs (with your example IDs)
$actors = Actor::whereIn('id', [1, 8, 20])->with('movies')->get();


// With the returned collection ($actor) you can reach the movies (for example loop through them)
foreach ($actor->movies as $movie) {
    echo $movie->title;
}

// If you want to reach the movies from the $actors collection
// Loop through the actors
foreach ($actors as $actor) {
    // Loop through every movie of the current looped actor
    foreach ($actor->movies as $movie) {
        echo $movie->title;
    }
}
```

[Laravel official docs reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: This foreach returns only the movies from 1 actor right?

Comment: Edited my answer with (multiple) movies of (multiple) actors as well.

Comment: Ok I think this is the right direction except I get the movie as a pivot and I don't know how to call it. $actor->movies returns null, but when I echo the result I see the movies in the pivot.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $movies = $movie_model->actors()->whereIn('id', $actor_ids);
```

Comment: This returns no results :(